# Getting: Property 'getFlower' not found on object of type 'ViewController *'

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm following "Sams Teach Yourself iOS 6" and I have tried troubleshooting this error without any success.

Here's my ViewController.h file:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *colorChoice;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *flowerView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *flowerDetailView;

- (IBAction)toggleFlowerDetail:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)getFlower:(id)sender;

@end
```

The error I'm getting is on this line, **[self.getFlower:nil];**, in the ViewController.m file:

```
@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.flowerDetailView.hidden=YES;
    [self.getFlower:nil];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)toggleFlowerDetail:(id)sender {
        self.flowerDetailView.hidden=! [sender isOn];
}

- (IBAction)getFlower:(id)sender {
    NSURL *imageURL;
    NSURL *detailURL;
    NSString *imageURLString;
    NSString *detailURLString;
    NSString *color;
    int sessionID;

    color=[ self.colorChoice titleForSegmentAtIndex:self.colorChoice.selectedSegmentIndex];

    sessionID=random() % 50000;

    imageURLString=[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"http://www.floraphotographs.com/showrandomios.php?color=%@&session=%d", color, sessionID];

    detailURLString=[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"http://floraphotographs.com/detailios.php?session=%d", sessionID];

    imageURL=[[NSURL alloc]initWithString:imageURLString];
    detailURL=[[NSURL alloc]initWithString:detailURLString];

    [self.flowerView loadRequest: [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:imageURL]];
    [self.flowerDetailView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:detailURL]];
    self.flowerDetailView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
}

@end
```

The method, getFlower, has already been declared in the header file so why can't I use it in the implementation file?

Comment: You have your answer below my friend, I say accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This:

```
[self.getFlower:nil];
```

should be:

```
[self getFlower:nil];
```

It's a method, not a property.